# Reading a UE3 .ini file by using Java's BufferedReader reads lesser number of lines than present in input file

Tags: java, file-handling, unreal-engine4, ini, filehandler

## Problem

I'm trying to read the configuration file for Gearbox Software's 2012 Video game "Borderlands 2".

- The problem i'm facing is that the input file i'm reading from is of
  **2,245 lines** and 77,344 length whereas the number of values in the map
  in which i'm reading this file into is only **859 lines** and 31,786
  length.
- It is not that the stream is getting closed prematurely because
  manual checking revealed that **the last lines are there, it's the
  random lines in the middle that are missing**.
- i even tried **Files.readAllLines()** but i cannot seem to read more
  than 859 lines from the input file.
- When i output this map to a new file using FileWriter, the number of
  lines is 860, with one extra blank line added in the middle of the
  program
- I have checked the other threads for reading .ini files. I will use ini4j or regular expressions once i figure out what i'm doing wrong here.

## My Map object

```
Map <String,String>config_vals=new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

## My Objects for Input

```
InputStream IS= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\V\\BC\\WillowEngine.ini");
Reader R=new InputStreamReader(IS);
BufferedReader BFR=new BufferedReader(R);
```

## Loop for reading the contents of the file

```
while((temp=BFR.readLine())!=null)
 {
    if(temp.indexOf("=")==-1)             //if not a key-value pair, put whitespace as value
     config_vals.put(temp,"");  
    else
    {
     int separator=temp.indexOf("=");     //separating a k-v pair from a file into map entry     
     config_vals.put(temp.substring(0,separator),temp.substring(separator+1,temp.length()));
    }
}
BFR.close();
System.out.println(config_vals.size());  // prints 859
```

I worked an hour or so yesterday and i'm unable to figure out what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you checked for duplicate keys? Maps only allow one value per key and you'd have to do something along `Map<String, List<String>>` to represent several values per key.

Comment: And the empty line halfway through might represent empty lines in the original input file...

Comment: @Erk You're absolutely right, i forgot that maps don't process duplicate keys and the file has some duplicate keys

Comment: @Erk The file has empty lines before each header but my output file only has a single blank line at a particular point nowhere near a header.

Comment: yes, because the Map only allows one empty string key. The LinkedHashMap works like the HashMap but it will keep the keys in the order of the first inserted key. It will not however break the contract of a Map: "A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html